# Displaying Total Records in ASP.NET PieChart on ToolTip

Tags: asp.net, charts, pie-chart, aspchart

I displayed the percentage in **ASP.NET Chart Control(PieChart)**.. But, When my mouse hovers on the chart, It has to Show the total Values instead of percentage value.. I tried several thing, but the Chart accepts only X and Y axis parameters, so my efforts are going waste..

I have a data table like

**Name Percentage Count**

**xxx   10% 1**

**yyy   40% 4**

**zzz   50% 5**

I wanted to bind name and percentage column to asp.net pie chart
as x and y value member and count column i wanted to show as tooltip of pie chart
presently am not able to bind the 3rd column in tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the name of the thing is the y value and the count is the x

```
foreach (Series s in Chart1.Series)
{
   s.ToolTip = "Name: #VALY\nPercentage: #PERCENT\nCount: #VALX";
}
```

there are [a lot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of other possibilities.